# getting iframe to use https with youtube when iframe is create in javascript?

Tags: iframe, youtube-api

Youtube allows videos to be downloaded via ssl, with a simple https prefix.  If I use the youtube api to create a player, the code looks like:

```
player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '350',
                width: '400',
                videoId: 'ut-WpR',
                playerVars: { 'controls': 1, 'fs': 1, 'autoplay': 1, 'autohide': 0, 'modestbranding': 1, 'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0},
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
```

I see no place to put an https.  Is there one?  Also, on a related topic, Internet explorer is unreliable with iframes.  Sometimes you have to do a 'refresh' to see them.  One person on this forum suggested that I append a random string to the URL of the iframe each time, which would prevent it from being cached.  (assuming that's the problem).  But how do you append anything given the code above - there is no way that I can see to append a fake random string.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

YouTube doesn't actually use HTTPS for video streams right now. The information in this old blog post still applies: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/02/https-support-for-youtube-embeds.html

That being said, you can load the player HTML and JS via HTTPS (just not the video stream). The YT.Player constructor should automatically create an iframe with an HTTPS src if the host page uses HTTPS—if it isn't doing that, please let us know.